# PHP parse a csv with multi-character delimiters

Tags: php, csv

We are attempting to parse a csv file that contains multi-character delimiters. Here is the file:

```
foo;bar
bar;"foo
foo"
"foo;foo";bar
```

... and here is the logic we're trying to use to parse the file:

```
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ';'. '"')) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
```

The problem is that when we run the logic, we get an exception stating that

> fgetcsv(): delimiter must be a single character

Is there a flag value or ini value that can be set in order to allow multi-character delimiters?

Comment: So what is your delimiter - is it `;"` or is it either `;` or `"`?

Comment: Are you sure those are multi-character delimiters? By looking at it, lines 2 and 3 are really the same line, it just has a new line character in the middle of value 2. And line 4 is 2 values with the first being a string with a semi-colon. By doing looking at it that way, you have 3 lines with 2 values each, and a parseable CSV with ; as a delimiter.

Comment: `;` is the delimiter and `"` is the text enclosure so that `;` in between `"` aren't seen as a delimiter.  Just use `;`.

Comment: That file looks a bit dodgy to me. What's the logic? In the first line, `;` clearly delimits the two records...and in the second line, you could argue that `"` joins `;` in delimiting the records. But that wouldn't apply to the third or fourth lines - in line 3 the `"` is by itself, so that breaks the pattern. And on line 4 the `"` appears at the start, which again means it cannot be a delimiter in that instance. Normally in a CSV there's just one delimiter character, and often `"` is used to enclose a field which happens to contain the delimiter character as a valid part of the data itself.

Comment: However in this case there appears to potentially be a problem - are you sure lines 2 and 3 aren't in fact supposed to be one line `bar; "foo foo"`? I suspect perhaps a sneaky newline character has crept in on line 2 and pushed part of the last field onto the next line, and thereby corrupted the file. Examine it in a text editor such as Notepad++ which can show you hidden characters and check what's happened there. I can't see how it would make sense any other way. The suggestion that it's a multi-character delimiter falls apart as soon as you look at the data closely.

Comment: The question is incomplete as others noted above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I talked with my colleague about the code. It turns out that the concatenation dot should actually be a comma.

Comment: "dot"... what dot? There are no dots in your example above. And a CSV files isn't actually required to use commas - almost anything can be used as the delimiter, including `;`. What isn't usual, is the multiple delimiter thing, which you erroneously identified as being used in your example data, and which we have explained to you about in the comments above - and you haven't made any response to that issue at all. Did you look for newlines as I suggested? Anyway I fail to see how this answer has anything to do with your question or sample data, to be honest. Can you clarify??

Comment: There is indeed a dot in the code sample if you look closely. It's being used to (wrongly) concatenate two strings -- the semicolon string and the double-quote string. Changing that dot to a comma fixes the situation, allowing us to use the semicolon as the delimiter (which was my coworker's original intention). It's not my code -- I just took it over from someone, and the guy made an honest typo that was easy to fix.

Comment: Oh I see you meant in the code not the data, apologies, I misread it

Comment: I still think there's a chance your CSV is corrupt though on lines 2 and 3